# How to migrate a jzy3d java project into android?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, opengl-es, jogl, jzy3d

I followed jzy3d's demo and made a 3D plot model with AnalysisLauncher.open() in IntelliJ, win10. It's working great. Now I need to migrate to Android so that the model can be displayed in a mobile application.
What kind of change is needed for my code? A sample project with any jzy3d surface plot would be ideal.

I read  the page [How to use jzy3d in android using eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938383/how-to-use-jzy3d-in-android-using-eclipse). The idea seems promising because jzy3d relies on JOGL 2 and OpenGL is cross-platform API. But I couldn't understand all the instructions by @Martin. Namely how do I replace AWT and 'derive CanvasNewtAwt'? I have no idea how to start the project in Android Studio. 
The jzy3d website(http://www.jzy3d.org/) also says 'Android supposed to work if enable approte JOGL jars'. How do I do this?

```java
import MyColorMap.ColorMapGrayColor;
import org.jzy3d.analysis.AbstractAnalysis;
import org.jzy3d.analysis.AnalysisLauncher;
import org.jzy3d.chart.factories.AWTChartComponentFactory;
import org.jzy3d.colors.Color;
import org.jzy3d.colors.ColorMapper;
import org.jzy3d.colors.colormaps.ColorMapGrayscale;
import org.jzy3d.colors.colormaps.IColorMap;
import org.jzy3d.maths.Coord3d;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Point;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Polygon;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Shape;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.rendering.canvas.Quality;

public class ChartPlot extends AbstractAnalysis {
    private int unitSize;
    private BufferedImage img;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnalysisLauncher.open(new ChartPlot("Forest.jpg", 10));
    }

    ChartPlot (String imgName, int unitSize) {
        img= getImg(imgName);
        this.unitSize= unitSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        int[][][] xycoords= getXYCoords(img, unitSize);
        float[][][] zcoords= getZCoords(img, unitSize);
        List<Polygon>[] polygonsArray= (List<Polygon>[])new List[COUNT_COLOR];
        for (int iColor=0; iColor < polygonsArray.length; iColor++) {
            polygonsArray[iColor]= getPolygons(xycoords, zcoords, iColor);
        }
        IColorMap[] colorMaps= new IColorMap[] {new ColorMapGrayscale(), new ColorMapGrayColor(ColorMapGrayColor.RED),
                new ColorMapGrayColor(ColorMapGrayColor.YELLOW), new ColorMapGrayColor(ColorMapGrayColor.BLUE),
                new ColorMapGrayscale()};
        Shape[] surfaces= new Shape[COUNT_COLOR];
        for (int iColor= 0; iColor < surfaces.length; iColor++) {
            surfaces[iColor]= iColor == INDEX_WHITE || iColor == INDEX_BLACK ?
                    getSurface_Global(polygonsArray[iColor], colorMaps[iColor]) :
                    getSurface_Local(polygonsArray[iColor], colorMaps[iColor]);
        }

        chart = AWTChartComponentFactory.chart(Quality.Advanced, getCanvasType());
        chart.getScene().getGraph().add(surfaces[INDEX_BLACK]);
        chart.getScene().getGraph().add(surfaces[INDEX_RED]);
        chart.getScene().getGraph().add(surfaces[INDEX_YELLOW]);
        chart.getScene().getGraph().add(surfaces[INDEX_BLUE]);
        chart.getScene().getGraph().add(surfaces[INDEX_WHITE]);
}
```

Comment: Jzy3d's CanvasNewtAwt wraps a JOGL NEWT canvas into an AWT Panel. As AWT doesn't work under Android (whereas NEWT does), you'll have to write a class like CanvasNewtAwt that will still use a JOGL NEWT canvas but that won't wrap it into an AWT Panel. Have you tried to use org.jzy3d.chart.factories.NewtChartComponentFactory? I fear that it still uses a bit AWT under the hood. Try to contact Martin Pernollet to get some help.

Comment: So you're saying I could use jzy3d in android if I place the chart in a NEWT canvas, which can be displayed in android? By the way how do I contact Martin Pernollet?

Comment: http://martin.pernollet.free.fr/cv/